# Chart copied to another workbook won't display horizontal axis in date format

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010

I'm trying to link a chart to another workbook in excel 2010. Copy-Paste does the trick, except for the dates on the horizontal axis. They keep showing as numbers (42515), but not in date format. I tried several things: change Axis type, convert source data to text (TEXT(42515; "dd/mm/yyyy")...

It's necessary that the link between the two charts stays, because I use it to automatically update the chart.

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Also, at least in Excel 2013 I cannot reproduce the problem. My chart is pasted into another workbook with the correct date formatting on the horizontal axis, and the values update once they are changed in the table in the first workbook.

Comment: Too bad, Tnx anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution:

Right click on the Chart -> Format Axis -> Number  -> Date